# Vector analysis query

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, vectors

[image]

I cannot understand how and why those two expressions are coming (the ones I have highlighted). Please explain.

Comment: When asking a homework question, you are supposed to show some effort, not just ask for straight-up answer. What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the component of the velocity is a function of $x$, thus $v(x)$, then, you could write a Taylor expansion around the point P with $x_p$, thus

$$ v(x)=v(x_p)+\left.\frac{dv}{dx}\right|_{x=x_p} x + O(x^2), \tag{1}$$

which linearizes the equations. As the quantities at point P in this equations are assumed to be known, you get

$$v(x)\approx v_1+\frac{dv_1}{dx} x \tag{2} $$

Now, what do you get when taking $v(\Delta x/2)$ and $v(-\Delta x/2)$?

The reasoning behind the linearization, is that the $O(x^2)$ vanished for $\Delta x\to 0$.

Comment: Why is $\Delta x$ being divided by 2?

Comment: Because P is halfway of the box of width $\Delta x$, and you want to have the velocity either of the walls, which is $\Delta x/2$ to the left or to the right.